# No "libs" directory found after reversing the android app using apktool?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I reversed an app (my own dummy app) using apktool.

`>apktool d testing.apk`

The last line of output in the terminal says `"I: Copying assets and libs..."` but there is no "libs" directory in the generated folder. 
Am I missing something here ?

I want to know which 3rd party libraries are being used. This can be found from "libs" directory but I am not getting this directory. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `my own dummy app` ... `I want to know which 3rd party libraries are being used.` **If the app is yours**, you **should know** which libraries it uses.

Comment: I built a tool that lets you know what libraries are used in apps - https://github.com/michaelcarrano/detective-droid

Comment: @michaelcarrano - I am having a look at it. Hope it solves my problem.

Comment: @v1h5 - Right now it only detects popular libraries that developers use. I personally got tired of using APKTool when trying to figure out how other developers built their apps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need apktool to get the libs. An APK is just a ZIP. Just unzip `testing.apk` and look for a `lib/` directory.

If it's not there, it may not use shared libraries. Or, they may be downloaded at runtime. To check, install and run the app such that you're sure it's used functions from the shared library. Then, pull the files off the device with:
`adb pull /data/data/<package name>/lib`